# Sticky footer when Page is larger than screen height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a project with a sidebar and in that side bar there i's like to have a sticky foot. The problem is the side bar scales to the height to the main page content. So if the main page content is bigger than the screen height, you end up with a big space under the footer if you scroll down the page.

I'd like the footer to stay at the bottom of the screen.

Hopefully my description makes sense.

```css
.sidebar {
   height: 100%;
}

.card{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 90vh;
}

.card-body{
    flex: 1;
}

.footer{
 }
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">TITLE</div>
    <div class="card-body">
      CONTENT
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    FEEDBACK CONTENT
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have some code you can post to show us what you have right now?

Comment: Agreed- code or at least a screenshot would help.  I particularly don't understand this sentence: "The problem is the side scales to the height to the main page content."

Comment: Sounds like the side-bar is 100% height, so when the main content is long, the side-bar is also long, but the side-bar content is not long, giving a large gap at the bottom of the side-bar.   It's not clear what solution is required to this *design* (not code) problem.  [update: footer at the "bottom" of the screen added]

Comment: Hi, I've added some code

Comment: Just put your side-bar-footer at the bottom of the side-bar wherever that may be.  Maybe you could use `100vh` - I've never tried it.

Comment: You can try this JavaScript : http://www.themeswild.com/read/fix-footer-always-bottom

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend `flexbox` and the `vh` CSS measurement.

This example will have the footer stuck to the bottom of the *viewport*, but will also allow the `.sidebar` to grow larger than the *window* height if required.  So the `.footer` will be stuck to the bottom with small content in the `.card` and will move downwards (requiring scrolling to see) if the content in `.card` gets bigger.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.sidebar {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.card {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">TITLE</div>
    <div class="card-body">
      CONTENT
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    FEEDBACK CONTENT
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you really want the `.footer` *stuck* to the bottom, even with a lot of contents in the `.card`, then you could try `position: fixed`.  I've added more content in the `.card` here so that you can more easily see what happens when it is larger than the body (the body & card content scroll, but `.footer` is always stuck to the bottom of the viewport).

```css
.card {
  /*
    .footer is out of the document flow,
    so make sure to leave enough space
    for it at the bottom of .card
  */
  margin-bottom: 1.6em;
}
.footer {
  /*
    here's the magic, fixed position
    at the bottom of the screen
  */
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  /*
    without a bg-color, this will get
    messed up with overflowing .card
    content
  */
  background-color: white;
  height: 1.6em;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">TITLE</div>
      <div class="card-body">
        CONTENT<br/>
        CONTENT<br/>
        CONTENT<br/>
        CONTENT<br/>
        CONTENT<br/>
        CONTENT<br/>
        CONTENT<br/>
        CONTENT<br/>
        CONTENT<br/>
        CONTENT<br/>
        CONTENT<br/>
        CONTENT<br/>
        CONTENT<br/>
        CONTENT<br/>
        CONTENT<br/>
        CONTENT<br/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      FEEDBACK CONTENT
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This does not seem, to me, to follow the requirment:  The side-bar-footer at the page size while the *main* content becomes larger.  This puts a footer over the top of the main content (even if it's called "sidebar" in your code, there's only one set of content, not separate sidebar/content).  Although the concept appears to be correct, so can you provide an example with side-bar + main-content?

Comment: Thank you, the first code example is pretty much how I currently have it set up, the problem is that since the side bar has a height 100% the footer has space underneath it, when the main page content is larger than the screen height.

Comment: You can try this : http://www.themeswild.com/read/fix-footer-always-bottom

Answer (score 0):

check this example. it works [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/)

`html` for this

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="content-inside">
    <h1>Sticky Footer with Negative Margin 2</h1>
    <p><button id="add">Add Content</button></p>
  </div>
</div>

<footer class="footer">
  Footer 
</footer>
```

`css` for this

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.content {
  min-height: 100%;
}
.content-inside {
  padding: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}
.footer {
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  background: #42A5F5;
  color: white;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

body {
  font: 16px Sans-Serif;
}
h1 {
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}
p {
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}
```